# How to perform a command in a shell on remote server immediately after deploying some code from intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, pycharm, webstorm

I have a web server running on a virtual machine and I need some actions (e.g. "service apache2 reload") to be performed there automatically after I'll deploy my code from Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically -- no way AFAIK.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3344 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

You may also watch related tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23938
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3239

---

The only **manual** solutions I may suggest right now are:

- either keep SSH console opened (IDE has it built-in) and execute such command manually once deployed
- or create "Remote SSH External Tools" entry that will do such job (connect and issue specified command) manually after deployment (once created you can assign custom shortcut to it so it can be run more easier).

In both cases -- check [this manual](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools).